# BC32208: Locals debug window doesn't work, along with quick watches

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2015

[Similar to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31650541/visual-studio-2015-errors-in-watches-and-no-value-pop-up-when-i-hover-over-varia), I'm having trouble with an old webforms project in vs2015. The code will compile and run without error.

If I enable a breakpoint and try to look at any value in a Quickwatch, I get the following error:

> error BC32208: Project already has a reference to assembly
>   '*projectname*.resources'. A second reference to
>   '*projectname*.resources.dll' cannot be added.

Similarly, if I break into the code and hover the mouse over a variable name then I do not get a pop-up containing the variable's current value.

I also looked at [this microsoft link](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/1419986/project-already-has-a-reference-to-assembly-when-try-to-view-variable-value) to no avail.

Is there a workaround for webforms?

My project doesn't have any localized [culture-code].resx files.

There's no assembly tab in project properties.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Amber Zhang from Microsoft contacted me to inform me that this has been resolved in [vs2015 update 2](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/news/vs2015-update2-vs.aspx). Downloaded and verified today. Thanks Amber!